# how do I extract the JSON value?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting and error response from server in android studio. how do I extract the values.

**Json:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "phone": [
      "The phone field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

**Code:**

```
 try {
     JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("OutPut", mJsonObject.getString("phone"));
     }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();                     
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java has some helpful answers

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: {"error":{"phone":["The phone field is required."]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your response is an `object` not an `array`. Try below:

```
String response = "{\"error\":{\"phone\":[\"The phone field is required.\"]}}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject errorObject = jsonObject.optJSONObject("error");
    JSONArray phoneArray = errorObject.getJSONArray("phone");

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneArray.length(); i++) {
        String  errorString = phoneArray.optString(i);
        Log.d("OutPut", errorString);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: He says {"error":{"phone":["The phone field is required."]}}  isn't the response but the error